# After ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED, why is AlarmManager running right away?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, android-reboot

### BootReceiver

```
override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
    if (intent.action == Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED) {
        val array = MyDatabase(context).getAllAlarm()

        val receiver = Intent(context, BootReceiver::class.java)
        receiver.action = "ALARM_SETTING"

        val trigger = Calendar.getInstance()
        for (i in array) {
            trigger.time = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm", Locale.getDefault()).parse(i.time)!!
            receiver.putExtra("trigger", trigger.timeInMillis)
            AlarmUtil.setAlarm(context, receiver, i.id, trigger.timeInMillis)
        }
    } else (intent.action == "ALARM_SETTING") {
        val trigger = intent.getLongExtra("trigger", 0)
        NotificationUtil.sendNotification(context, name, id, trigger)
    }
}
```

### AlarmUtil

```
class AlarmUtil {
    companion object {
        fun setAlarm(context: Context, intent: Intent, id: Int, calendar: Long) {
            val alarmManager = context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
            val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context.applicationContext, id, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)


            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar, pendingIntent)
            } else {
                alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar, pendingIntent)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, when the mobile phone reboots, this code brings the alarm array stored in SQLiteDatabase and makes the alarm sound. If you look at setAlarm() in AlarmUtil, I wrote a code that makes it cry at the time specified in AlarmManager. The problem is that all the alarms stored in the array will be cleared at once regardless of the time specified in the alarm array (I implemented it as Notification). Isn't it normal to cry at the `calendar` time you put in the second argument of `setExactAndAllowWhileIdle` or `setExact`? Why do all the alarms cry at once as soon as the phone turns on again?

### [EDIT]

[image]

The following picture is a situation where the phone is turned off and on after setting the alarm to ring at 02:22. The system time is `2020/11/02 02:21`, but the trigger time I set to ring is `2020/11/02 02:22`. In other words, the alarm goes off as soon as the time runs out. I want to take a log and show it, but the moment I turn off my phone, the app dies, so I couldn't see the log.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you are passing older time as trigger time.
You should pass time in the future.
Check db time if it is less than now() than add a day

Comment: Thank you for your response. As you can see from the ```BootReceiver``` code, the **trigger** momentarily calls ```Calendar.getInstance()```, and the **trigger** time is reset within the for statement. As a result of passing the **trigger** value as a Notification, the future time you speak of is stamped. It was never **older time**.

Comment: Can you log the time you are passing to AlarmManager?

Comment: I uploaded a picture of your log.

Comment: Can you log both trigger time and device time?

Comment: Maybe you are ignoring timezone when you are logging log the time in miillis  not date presentation

Comment: The time zone is set to Locale.getDefault(), so there is no problem with the setting. We edited the question and uploaded additional photos, so please check it out.

Comment: Pls log timeinmillis value of both device time and trigger time

Comment: You were right. In SimpleDateFormat, System.currentMillis is smaller than trigger, but TimeInMillis is larger than System.currentMillis. How can I fix it...?